# Transact SQL Minus

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have seen is that the operator **MINUS** doesn't exists here. I have been reading that I can use `EXCEPT` but is not working for me.

What I want is to get the sum of a value from one table and the sum of the value of other table and subtract them, for instance:

```
Select sum(ipaq.cant) from tablee12a as paq inner join xtable15 as ipaq on paq.pkey = ipaq.ppkey where paq.pkey = '1ke1'
Except --Minus
Select sum(galvet.cantidad) from tablee12a as paq inner join tableegv as galvet on paq.pkey = galvet.paqkey where paq.pkey = '1ke1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `MINUS` and `EXCEPT` are *set* operators. If you just have two scalars and want to subtract one from the other, compute the scalars as subselects and use `-`:

```
SELECT
(
Select sum(ipaq.cant) from tablee12a as paq inner join xtable15 as ipaq on paq.pkey = ipaq.ppkey where paq.pkey = '1ke1'
) -
(
Select sum(galvet.cantidad) from tablee12a as paq inner join tableegv as galvet on paq.pkey = galvet.paqkey where paq.pkey = '1ke1'
)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. I will accept the anwser in 10 minutos because I can't do it now!
But Minus is possible use in transact sql?

Comment: @greatWallace - T-SQL has `EXCEPT` instead of `MINUS` - but both operators are set operators, as I say. They take the whole set of rows from one result set and remove all rows that also occur in the second result set (matching on all columns). The result of such an operator will never contain a row that didn't already exist in the first result set.

Answer (score -1):

You are just looking for the subtraction operator.  That said, I'm wondering if the inner join is actually necessary.

Does this simpler version do what you want?

```
select (select sum(ipaq.cant)
        from xtable15 as ipaq  
        where ipaq.pkey = '1ke1'
       ) - 
       (sum(galvet.cantidad)
        from tableegv galvet 
        where galvet.paqkey = '1ke1'
       )
```